# Getting Host field from HTTP request in BaseHTTPRequestHandler

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I'm writing a script using BaseHTTPRequestHandler class. And in `do_GET(self)` method I need to get the content of the `Host` field from the HTTP request. I can do it by regexping the `str(self.headers)` like proposed here: [Determine site domain in BaseHTTPServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958408/determine-site-domain-in-basehttpserver), but it's kinda ugly and I wonder if there's cleaner way to do that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The attribute [self.headers](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/basehttpserver.html?highlight=basehttprequesthandler#BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.headers) is a dictionary-like structure, so you can do this:

```
def do_GET(self):
    host = self.headers.get('Host')
```

When the header does not exist, `None` is returned.